# Install mono on Centos7

Tags: mono, centos7

I use this steps to install mono on Centos7 and it worked for me for days.

```
mkdir /mono
wget http://download.mono-project.com/repo/xamarin.gpg -P /mono
rpm --import /mono/xamarin.gpg
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/
yum install -y mono-complete
```

And now it keeps failing and can't install mono:

```
failure: repodata/bd6e4ea2b820dd6b71fd4fca044931e043e411cc2ba8e362b8249951474224b6-primary.sqlite.bz2 from download.mono-project.com_repo_centos_: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try. 
http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos/repodata/bd6e4ea2b820dd6b71fd4fca044931e043e411cc2ba8e362b8249951474224b6-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

Is there a problem with the repository right now? Or should i install it from a different source?

It's a Centos7 host running on Azure in the North Europe region.

Comment: It looks like a problem with the DNS because it is running correctly from a VM in "East US" or "West Europe" region.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the steps below to install mono done

```
yum-config-manager --add-repo http://download.mono-project.com/repo/centos-beta/
yum repolist
```

and finally

```
yum install -y mono-complete
```

[Install Mono](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJafm.png)

Comment: for Visual Basic support in `mono` on Centos you also need to `yum install -y mono-basic`